# Visual Studio Task Runner - The same task runs again if csproj file changes

Tags: visual-studio, gulp

When Gulp task is bound to 'project open', the task will be started again and again if the project file get changed. So we end up having multiple running instances of the same task.

How to get around this so that the runner recognizes that the task is already running and won't start it again on project open binding?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear the VS Task Runner is not the greatest thing in the world. It is super sensitive to specific settings and malfunctions at will without changing anything.

With that said bind the task to "Before Build", and not to "Project Open". I'm guessing that you are doing that in order to install npm, or bower packages since that is a task that you don't want to run on every build.

All in all, save yourself a few hours of headache after headache and use the command line outside of Visual Studio. If you are on Windows and you don't like the prompt, I don't either. It sucks. And that's an understatement.

Use [Cmdr](http://cmder.net/) and love the prompt again.